# Find how by which actions users move through my website

Tags: google-analytics

I have a very simple e-commerce.

As you can see in the image, people move from the product page to the checkout page and then in most cases back to the product page.

Might be that people just click on the back button, but maybe there is some other way (maybe some error?) that makes them go back to the product page. I would love to know what people do on the checkout page to go to the product page so I can think of what to do to avoid this and make the confirm their order.

Google Analytics only shows me the flow, but not the actions taken.

Is there any way or tool that can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Google Analytics, [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/) seems like an obvious solution.
It is free, and it's possibilities are almost limitless, as it can help you track almost anything that a visitor does on your website.
If you want more visual data, checkout [Hotjar](https://www.hotjar.com/).
Of course, there are plenty more tools out there, these are just my personal preferences.